# Autocomplete / Autofill with Polymer input elements (gold-email-input)

Tags: autocomplete, polymer, polymer-1.0, autofill

I'm having an issue getting Chrome's autofill and/or autocomplete working with Polymer input elements, such as gold-email-input.  I've tried setting the `autocomplete` attribute of the gold-email-input component to `on` and I've also tried setting it to `email`.  The autofill box appears, but selecting an entry from the autofill selections does not populate the control.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form is="iron-form">
  <gold-email-input></gold-email-input>
</form>
```

This tends to work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `autocomplete` attribute, as it's [already set to `autocomplete=email`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-email-input/blob/e6373a1/gold-email-input.html#L73).

I think we need to see a sample of your code in context because the input automatically populates for me when I select the autofill suggestion:

[image]

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tudevet/edit?html,output)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your input elements in a form element. 
This works for me:

```
<form>
     <paper-input id="user"
                   autocomplete="email"
                   label="Username or email"
                   value="{{user}}"
      </paper-input>
      <paper-input id="pwd"
                   autocomplete="current-password"
                   label="Password"
                   value="{{pwd}}"
      </paper-input>
</form>
```