# My login passwords won't autocomplete when I enter my email in polymer 2

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, polymer

In my polymer 2 app I have something like this:

```
<form class="styling" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="styling" >
        <label>email</label>
        <input name="email" autocomplete="email">
    </div>
    <div class="styling" >
        <label>email</label>
        <input name="password" autocomplete="current-password">
    </div>
    <div class="styling">
        <a class="styling" on-tap="doRequestFunction">Login<a>
    </div>
</form>
```

My issue is there are a lot of sources saying what works and what doesn't and I've tried removing the outer div, I've tried changing the email to a username, I've tried to change the `<a>` to an `<input type="submit">`. I've also tried to add an invisible username input below the email input. I have a database element that does my ajax calls so ideally I'd like to just call the request function on a form submit, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this because it wants me to perform the action with a file or something like that.

TL;DR is there a way to do this:

```
<form class="styling" onSubmit="doTheRequestFunction" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="styling" >
        <label>email</label>
        <input name="email" autocomplete="email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="styling" >
        <label>email</label>
        <input name="password" autocomplete="current-password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="styling">
        <input class="styling" type="submit">Login</input>
    </div>
</form>
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in polymer and the ways that do don't request for the users password and are depreciated anyways. Using Chrome primarily.

EDIT: Please, no JQuery, only Javascript. I don't know what JQuery is doing half the time and it's sloppy.

Comment: So you want the browser to autocomplete the password for you right? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, IE. They all tend to have different solutions, but from my research if I can solve this problem for chrome it is more likely to work for the other two.

Comment: It usually works for me when having everything described [here](https://superuser.com/a/573625) and without the need of placing `autocomplete="on"`. But I'll see if I come up with something.

Comment: It'd be nice if that was all I needed. It seems like it's been an unsolved issue for Polymer for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boys, I found it.

[paper-input autocomplete fails to fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445468/paper-input-autocomplete-fails-to-fill)

This is a polymer specific issue I was having. Currently polymer requested support for their auto-fill apparently and it's still not there. This is the solution for now. Pop that bad boy into you index.html and weep tears of joy.

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete` is an HTML attribute (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp). It's either on or off.  It's designed to tell the browser whether it should attempt to autocomplete a field or not.  The default is `on` so you shouldn't have to set it unless you're trying to prevent the browser from autocompleting.

Try to remove all your `autocomplete` attributes, and submit your form.  The browser should ask you if you want to save your username and password at which point it should be populated next time you come to your form.

Also, you have an bad tag on the end of your submit button: `</inoput>`

`<input type="submit" value="Send Request">` should be fine.

Comment: I've added my actual code. The first code was sample code so people could understand what I was doing and not get lost in all the attributes and styling, but I can't really form submit using my current method can I. Is that what I'm getting? If so what should I do?

Comment: and no, my current code does not work. The form doesn't want to use my functions and I don't know how to get it to want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it

```
<input name="password" type="password"/>
```

So if input field has attribute type as password it will trigger browser to remember.

Comment: This does not work sadly. It requires a lot more finagling than that explanation though to make that work without having to deal with polymer anyways.